# How to have the Bookmarks toolbar show up on Firefox 4?

Tags: firefox, upgrade

I've upgraded Firefox from 3 to 4 beta8. My Bookmarks toolbar has disappeared and I can't find the option to make it appear again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've since learned of **2** ways to do this:

- `View` menu -> `Toolbars` -> `Bookmarks Toolbar`
- Right-click on toolbar -> `Bookmarks Toolbar`

Comment: You can also just right click a toolbar to get a checkbox menu of all of them